# Binding in winform like in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I want to bind a winform's form's Width property to Text on a label so label's text gets updated every mouse movement I made. Currently I only achieved updating when some element on a form is clicked but not continious updating(like if you change text in Resize handler). How to do this thing?

Answer (score 3):

You can bind to the Width property by doing this:

```
label1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this, "Width"));
```

The problem there is the form isn't notifying the framework that the property has changed.  Your easiest best bet is likely to just do it the meat and potatoes way:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e);
    label1.Text = this.Width.ToString();
}
```

**EDIT:** Okay, if you really want to use data binding, here is a way that works (but is like reaching around your head to scratch your ear):

Add an object data source to your form and set the DataSource to type "System.Windows.Forms.Form".

Next, add some code:

```
public Form2()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   this.formBindingSource.DataSource = this;

   Binding binding = new Binding("Text", this.formBindingSource, "Size", true);

   binding.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(binding_Format);

   label1.DataBindings.Add(binding);
}

void binding_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    Size size = (Size)e.Value;
    e.Value = size.Width.ToString();
}
```

So like I said, it's complete overkill, but it works.

Comment: Yeah, data binding for something like this is just overkill imo. +1

Comment: Binding will not working propertly, because default data source update mode is On Validation

Comment: I added a way to do databinding (but it's complete overkill)

Answer (score 1):

The Resize event is the correct event to handle.  I'm not sure what continuous updating you are looking for, but if the form changes size, Resize Event fires.  I believe this also includes size changes for minimize/maximize/restore.  This should cover all changes to the size of the form.

```
private void OnFormResize(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
      Form frm = (Form) sender;
      txtWidth.Text = frm.Size.Width.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, binding to the Width property will not working correct because Form hasn't WidthChanged event.

You can bind to the Size property and use formating to format that

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var binding = new Binding("Text", this, "Size", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        binding.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(binding_Format);

        label1.DataBindings.Add(binding);
    }

    void binding_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value is Size)
        {
            e.Value = ((Size)e.Value).Width.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, it didn't work.  I even implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on my own FormClass but no dice.