# Binding Form's Size and Location properties to Labels' Text property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I'm used to **data-binding** in **WPF** which has a complete support for it and I know that it exists but is much more limited in **Windows Forms**.

Just out of curiosity I wanted to do some really basic data-bindings:

- bind the `Size` property of the current `Form` to a `Label`'s `Text` property
- do the same for the `Location` property

Is it possible and if yes how to implement it?

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032194/binding-in-winform-like-in-wpf ?

Comment: Your 1st binding should use "Location" as the data member name instead of "Position".  If you fix that error then it should work.

Comment: @RogerN Ouch so stupid :) But why does it break the second binding too ? Thanks.

Comment: @LarsTech the original code was flawed and RogerN spotted it. I've fixed it and made it a community wiki so hopefully it will help future developers with the same need. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can implement it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Label positionOutput = new Label { Dock = DockStyle.Top };
        positionOutput.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "Location");

        Label sizeOutput = new Label { Dock = DockStyle.Top };
        sizeOutput.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "Size");

        this.Controls.Add(positionOutput);
        this.Controls.Add(sizeOutput);
    }
}
```

It works with `Location` and `Size` because for both the `Form` class provides dedicated data-binding events: `LocationChanged` and `SizeChanged`.

But with `Width` or `Height` you would not benefit from a real-time automatic update because there is no `WidthChanged` or `HeightChanged` events.